# Angular form validation for manual input and imported input

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, import, error-handling

I have a form that can have inputs manually entered by a user AND imported in from elsewhere.

I am struggling with how to do validation. I want to do onblur if inputted manually, but I was told that onblur wouldn't work for imported data. For imported  data you should validate any time the model changes... but that's bad practice for inputs that are manually added.

Is there a method that will work for both methods of input or will I have to write two forms, one with the manual entry and one with imported?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the real ask is but have you tried ng-dirty, ng-touched or ng-pristine flags?

These are the flags which can be used for forms.

Comment: Yes. Using ng-dirty or ng-touched would be the same as using the method for imported data-- validating when the model changes.